# How to create a random grid 3x3 of 3 different arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, class, sorting

I am working on a javaScript project and I am supposed to create a 3x3 grid using 3 different arrays (each one of them should have its own random order) and the print the result by using a class method.Is there a way to randomize each arrays class instance ? See code below:

```js
const my_arr = ['^', 'O', '░', '*'];

let field = []

for (let i = 0; i < my_arr.length; i++) {
  const randomIndex1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  field.push(my_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)])
  //
  //field.push(my_arr[randomIndex])
}

//console.log(field)


class Field {
  constructor(field) {
    this.field = field.reverse();
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.field.join(''))
  }
}


const myField1 = new Field([field])
const myField2 = new Field([field])
const myField3 = new Field([field])

console.log(`${myField1.print()}\n${myField2.print()}\n${myField3.print()}`)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you need to make your random generating code into a function and call it.

Comment: your print method returns undefined.....

Answer (score 1):

You're not randomizing the array for each Field. You're initializing `field` once, and then passing that to the constructor, so all 3 `Field`s have the same array values. If you move the field generating/randomizing logic to a callable function, you can generate a new array for each `Field`.

`print()` is doing `console.log`, and you're calling it by doing `console.log(myField1.print());`, so it's essentially doing `console.log(console.log(myField1.print()));`.

So you can change `print()` to just *return* the joined array, and then the single `console.log` at the bottom of your script works as expected.

Lastly, you were passing `[field]` to the constructor like `const myField1 = new Field([field])`, but that's passing an array of arrays (`[field]` vs `field`).

```js
const my_arr = ['^', 'O', '░', '*'];
  
function generateRandomArray() {
  let field = []

  for (let i = 0; i < my_arr.length; i++) {
    const randomIndex1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    field.push(my_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)])
  }
  
  return field;
}


class Field {
  constructor(field) {
    this.field = field.reverse();
  }
  print() {
    return this.field.join('');
  }
}


const myField1 = new Field(generateRandomArray())
const myField2 = new Field(generateRandomArray())
const myField3 = new Field(generateRandomArray())

console.log(`${myField1.print()}\n${myField2.print()}\n${myField3.print()}`)
```

Comment: @SimoneGhilotti your question initially included `i < my_arr.length` as the loop condition, but that's comparing `i` to the length of the symbol array (there are 4 different symbols, so it's generating new arrays of length 4). If you want the generated arrays to only be 3 items long, then change the conditional to `i < 3`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [array's sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with `Math.random` to shuffle the values:

```js
function randomizeArray(arr) {
  return [...arr].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
}

const arr = ['^', 'O', '░', '*'];

console.log(randomizeArray(arr).join());
console.log(randomizeArray(arr).join());
console.log(randomizeArray(arr).join());
```

The randomizeArray function above does the following:

1. creates a copy of the array via spread `[...arr]` because we want it to be independent, unaffected by other manipulations to the source array.
2. "sorts" the array randomly via `sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)`. Sort functions return a positive number, negative number, or zero to indicate whether an item should be before, after, or equal to another. Generating a random number between 0 and 1 and subtracting 0.5 gives us an (approximately) even distribution of positive and negative numbers.

Comment: FYI that random method is not really a good way to get random. And OPs will repeat, not sure it they actually want it to repeat.

Comment: What do you mean it's "not a good way to get random"?

Comment: explained in the one answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array